# findOneAndUpdate document with array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Two questions here.

1. What is the correct way to findOneAndUpdate when there is an array? The example below errors with **err MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to embedded failed for value**.
2. Should you arrays of objects become separate collections?

*** Example ***

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product_name: String
});

var purchaseOrderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    purchaseOrderNo: Number,
    products: [ProductSchema]
  }
);

const purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder(req.body);

PurchaseOrder.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.body._id },
  {
    $set: req.body,
    $push: req.body.products
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
)
.then((result) => {
  console.log('result', result);
  res.status(200).json(result);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('err', err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});


const body = {
  _id: 'skjdhflksjdf',
  purchaseOrderNo: 1,
  products: [
    {
      _id: '111',
      product_name: 'Cup'
    },
    {
      _id: '222',
      product_name: 'Spoon'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new purchase order or update it, why is the line const purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder(req.body)

Comment: That's express. The object is req.body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ProductSchema` the `type` of `_id` field to set to `ObjectId`. The product id 111 and 222 are not a valid `ObjectId` and it fails to cast it. You can update the type of `_id` in `ProductSchema` to `Number` for this to work

```js
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  product_name: String
});
```